# Recover CentOS - blinking cursor on boot

Tags: centos

I broke CentOS trying to edit a file I probably shouldn't have touched in an attempt to get a user to automatically login.

The instruction was this:

```
Modify following line in /etc/init/tty.conf
exec /sbin/mingetty $TTY to exec /sbin/mingetty –autologin username password $TTY
```

Now when I boot I get a blinking cursor, entering text does nothing. How can I fix this? Obviously getting to /etc/init/tty.conf can fix the problem, I just don't know how to do that with the OS in it's current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot from a LiveCD version of Linux and modify the file from there.

Try to undo what you changed and see if that fixes it.